# Awk script not listing specific column

Tags: shell, parameters, awk

Using awk I have written this script but it's not working properly. Even I expected just only specific column it's displaying me total column of information.

```
n=0
echo  "Enter which column you want: "
read  n
awk '{print $($n)}' out.txt
```

I would like to have only specific column for the value of `n`.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no parameter substitution within single quotes. Use

```
awk '{print $'$n'}' out.txt
```

or use an awk variable as in

```
awk -v n="$n" '{print $n}' out.txt
```

Comment: Thank you i will try that and gonna let you know .